# Is it good to make all the elements that have the same style carry the same class name in a css framework?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I'm building my own CSS library or framework, whatever you would like to call it ,but I'm facing a problem where if I have 10 `li` tag , they will all have the same classes which is `.pl{ padding-left:10px} .mr{ margin-right:10px}` and another attributes as needed , which approache should I follow ? create a class that holds all that attributes and assign that class to the `li`
like that

```
.list-item{
margin-right:10px;
padding-left:10px;
}

<li class="list-item"/>
```

or give all the required attribute to all li I will make like this

```
<li class="mr-10 pl-10"/>
```

knowing if i followed the first approach the use of the library will be much more less than the second one

(my library is considered of a css file that carry different class names of a specific attributes as `.mr-10 => margin-right:10px` and so on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is really **opinion based** and depending on the **size of the project**. If you know, that you will use that padding and margin in other cases I would seperate them into two classes, like you did (`.mr` and `.pl`). However, if you want to join them together I would prefer to assign a class to the parent, thus the `<ul>` or `<ol>`, like so:

```
.my-special-list li{
   margin-right:10px;
   padding-left:10px;
}

<ul class="my-special-list">
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

The advantage of this method is, that you don't need to give each `<li>` a class.

Comment: what do you mean by 2 classes for it? like you would create a class that hold the 2 attributes and a classes for each attribute alone?

Comment: You said that there are two classes: `.pl{ padding-left:10px} .mr{ margin-right:10px}`. I meant, that if you need that margin and padding in other cases across the website, then I would keep them seperate so you can use them individually.